# Getting key of json object in C using YAJL

Tags: c, json, yajl

I am trying to get the key for an object in yajl in C

```
{
"Val":"box"
}
```

so for above code, I am trying to get the key 'Val'. But so far I am not able to find any way to do so. I know how to get the keys from the array but not from the object.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet?

Comment: I haven't found a solution. I switched the library from YAJL to CJSON as the requirements for my project changed. But with both libraries, I had to assume the keys were pre-defined.